# Install Oracle 11.2.0.4 to Win2012srvR2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, oracle-11g

I'm starting to prepare my server to install a new version of Oracle 11.2.0.4 Database. I'm reading some forum... there is problem about thin installation ? Is supported Oracle 11.2.0.4  version into Win2012srvR2?  Can you give me the correct link to download it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is necessary to connect to:
[Patchset 13390677](https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/PatchDetails/handle_plat_lang_change?plat_lang=226P&patch_file=&file_id=&password_required=&password_required_readme=&merged_trans=&aru=16716375&patch_num=13390677&patch_num_id=1730815&default_release=80112040&default_plat_lang=233P&default_compatible_with=&patch_password=&orderby=&direction=&no_header=0&sortcolpressed=&tab_number=) and download the patches.

but to enable download is necessary have a CSI (Customer Support Identifier).
It might be provided to you by your Customer User Administrator (CUA)

To have a CSI associating with your account, is necessary to speak to the person in your company who is your Administrator, who should be able to log on themselves and connect you to the company's support contract with Oracle (hence giving you the CSI you need).
You cannot download things that are not readily available on the download page (i.e. those things only available through Oracle Support) **if you do not have a support contract.**